# Adding click to dynamically generated divs Jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm creating a bunch of Divs based on the number items in an array that I recieve from an AJAX. All of the divs have a unique Id and I want to add a Click event to each of the generated Divs.
I want the user to click on one of the generated divs which will then post some data.
This is the code I use but it doesn't work.

```
c=data.length

            for(i=0;i<c;i++){

                $('#result').prepend('<div class="validation" id="lv_'+i+'">'+data[i]+'</div> ');
                $("#lv_"+i).live('click', function(data){
                .$post("setLocation", {lv: lv}, function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
            });

        }
```

Comment: With jQuery 1.7 `live()` has been deprecated to use `on()`. While this doesn't address your specific question, it's worth investigating.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a certain event handler fire on all divs that have the class `validation`, whether dynamically added or not, you'd ideally use `on`

```
$(document).on("click", ".validation", function() {} );
```

If you're using an older version of jQuery, here's how you would do it with live:

```
$(".validation").live("click", function() {} );
```

Or, better than `live` would be `delegate`

```
$(document).delegate(".validation", "click", function() {} );
```

The reason why `delegate` and `on` are preferable to `live` is because `live` will go through the existing dom, and attach the relevant handler to all discovered elements.  `delegate` and `on` simply listen for events to bubble up, and fire the handler when the selector matches.  As a result, `delegate` and `on` are more performant.

Comment: @rzclfy - sure thing!  If you're using jQuery pre-1.7 delegate is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#lv_"+i).on("click", {lv: lv}, function(data))
```